# For a android system, do anyone know or has anyone tried to use getScanResult() to get multiple BSSIDs for 1 network name(SSID)?

Tags: android, android-wifi

If I use getScanResult() I will be able to get the information about different networks but for example if I am in a school where all access points are under network(SSID) "The school". Will getScanResult() filter out other access points than the one it's closest to and only return 1 BSSID for that network?

Answer (score 0):

You should get all BSSID entries that are in radio range, even if they are the same ESSID.  The WiFi driver could hide this from you; but I haven't seen that happen with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

getScanResults() will return all responding networks.

However, the list of known networks kept by WifiManager does not distinguish BSSID, but only SSID, so if the SSID matches Android will attempt to connect.

Comment: so what should i do to acquire that multiple BSSID information?

Comment: The scan results will show any responding networks, so if you have several in the scan with a shared SSID and different BSSIDs you'll get them all.  It's just that android will try to connect if the SSID matches a known network: it doesn't care about the BSSID.